# Using a Master Page - Display a Search Box on all pages, Except one

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a master page to add a search box to the navigation bar on all my pages, but I also have a dedicated search page that has it's own search box. I would like the navigation search box to show up on every page except the dedicated search page. What's the best way to accomplish this?

I'm presently including the navigation search box like so:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

      (other page stuff)

        <div id="menu">


                       (Other menu Stuff)       

                <asp:Panel ID="sSearchBox" runat="server" DefaultButton="sButton" CssClass="searchBox">
                        <asp:Label ID="sLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="sLabel">Search</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="sText" CssClass="sText" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="sButton" runat="server"  EnableTheming="True" ToolTip="Search" 
                        PostBackUrl="~/search.aspx" CssClass="sButton" />
                </asp:Panel>

        </div> <!-- End Menu -->
</form>
```

Comment: if you only want to hide the search box on the search page then do what @Paul Keister said.  But you can also specify different master page for the search page if you want a completely different look and feel for the master page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in the Page_Load event for your search page:

```
        var master = (MyMasterPageType)Page.Master;
        master.sSearchBox.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! The above technique resulted in a "inaccessible due to protection level" error. I got it to work by adding a public property to the master page.